# Enter and exit module environments?

Tags: command-line, drivers, bash, bashrc

I apologize for being a complete linux noob! I have also asked this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1282166/enter-and-exit-module-environments), but figured I should better move it to a dedicated Ubuntu forum:

I am trying to use [OpenAI gym](https://gym.openai.com/docs/) in Ubuntu. After I first did the installation, my command line in the terminal went from looking like

```
user@localhost:~$
```

to

```
(gym) user@localhost:~$
```

and I could execute files such as

```
(gym) user@localhost:/mnt/e/MyOpenAIstuff$ python script.py
```

which require the gym module.

Now when I start the terminal again, it starts in the `user@localhost:~$` state and when I try to run a script it does not recognize the `gym` module by saying that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym'`. I suspect that I need to issue some command to get the terminal back into the

```
(gym) user@localhost:~$
```

state before using gym in my scripts. What command should I use to enter such a module state?

PS:

So far I tried adding

```
export GYM_PATH="/home/user/gym/bin:$GYM_PATH"
```

to `.bashrc` and calling `source ~/.bashrc`, which unfortunately did not fix the issue.

EDIT:

At this point I figured out that I have to do `export GYM_PATH="/home/user/gym:$GYM_PATH"`, but then I got an error that some environment dependencies were missing.

Then I ran the installation command again `pip install -e '.[all]'` and it actually installed some components (don't know why they have not been there after first installation).

If I try to run the script now, I still get the error:

> [2018-01-03 11:43:39,443] Making new env: BreakoutDeterministic-v4
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "envi.py", line 11, in 
>       env.render()
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> File "/home/UNIXuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
>   packages/pyglet/canvas/**init**.py", line 82, in get_display
>       return Display()
>
> File "/home/UNIXuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/canvas/xlib.py", line 86, in **init**
>       raise NoSuchDisplayException('Cannot connect to "%s"' % name)
>   pyglet.canvas.xlib.NoSuchDisplayException: Cannot connect to "None"

I apologize, this is quickly getting into troubleshooting gym itself and not Ubuntu. I'll be greatful if you have any suggestions at this point, but probably I should now ask the gym people about this...

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @nixpower To install I did `git clone https://github.com/openai/gym` then `cd gym` and then `pip install -e '.[all]'`, as they describe on their webpage. At this point I figured out that I have to do `export GYM_PATH="/home/user/gym:$GYM_PATH"`, but then I get an error that some environment dependencies are missing. This is rather strange since it worked fine after installation...

Comment: Can you edit your answer and append information about the environment dependencies being missing?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are replacing `user` with your actual username, correct?

Comment: @nixpower Yes, I used `user` to make this forum post generic. I updated the question with further discoveries.

Comment: That last batch of errors looks like an error with the code, as it gets past the part where it imports `gym`. I suppose the issue is solved (at least on the Ubuntu/gym side), then?

Comment: @nixpower I guess so! I will add an answer describing some details on how to choose the proper path to export.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with importing the gym module was mainly in choosing the correct installation directory.

Since the installation is carried out as

```
git clone https://github.com/openai/gym
cd gym
pip install -e '.[all]'
```

the module itself is not located in `~/gym` but actually in `~/gym/gym`. So to provide a path to a folder containing the module `gym` folder we have to use:

`/home/user/gym`

not `/home/user`.

EDIT:

As an alternative, one can do

```
source activate gym
```

to get the terminal into the

```
(gym) user@localhost:~$
```

state, which will automatically search for all dependencies in the correct place when you run your scripts afterwards.